# C# Class Not Seen By Visual Studio, But Library Included

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, graphics

I have begun coding in C# on the side. I started a simple test program from a tutorial. To my surprise the project doesn't recognize certain libraries despite those libraries being listed with a using directive. Specifically in this case Bitmap; I included it using the "using" directive without a problem. I cannot however simple write Bitmap in my code; I instead have to make a direct reference. I know this is something simple based on my lack of experience with this code and development environment (Visual Studio Express 2012 Windows Desktop). The code is below. I have tried searching for solutions however several of the key words are extraordinarily generic so Googling this has not been fruitful. Any and all help appreciated; if there is additional info needed please ask and I will update this post.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Drawing.Bitmap;
using System.Drawing.Graphics;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Test
{
static class Program
{

    int GetPixel(int x, int y)
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(1, 1, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
```

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly, arguably with a bit more flesh, your comment should be the answer. :)

Comment: Something is not correct in your usings. You need only System.Drawing to write Bitmap without the namespace

Comment: Always include full and exact error messages in your question.

Comment: BTW, use `var` instead of typing the class name twice in the same line of code. C# is much better than java, if that's where you come from ;)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Every error that OP complained about was included...

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly Make what public?

Comment: @Moo-Juice I don't think making anything public/private has anything to do with OP's problem.

Comment: @Michael nevermind, i did not read full question and made wrong assumption.

Comment: @Michael, my bad... should have read more thoroughly.

Comment: @Michael - except the compilere error(s). Which are ususally quite explanatory and avoid much confusion.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I suppose... I just assumed that the post was edited for brevity.

Comment: How did you miss: `Error 1  A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' is a type not a namespace` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you can't see it, is because you included the class with the using directive, not the namespace that it belongs to.

Change

```
using System.Drawing.Bitmap;
using System.Drawing.Graphics;
```

To

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Now, you'll be able to access the Bitmap and Graphics class without having to to type the full reference

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
```